# Given this theorem, Why is Subgraph Isomorphism NP hard and not polynomial?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, np-complete, graph-isomorphism

So, I read the following Theorem by Matousek and Thomas:

Given graphs $G$ and $H$, we want to check if there is a subgraph $S \subseteq H$ such that $S$ and $G$ are isomorphic.

Then, if the maximum degree of $G$ is bounded by a constant $c$ and if $H$ is a partial $k$-tree, then the Subgraph Isomorphism, and Induced Subgraph Isomorphism problems are solvable in $O(|V(G)|^{k+1} \cdot |V(H)|)$ time.

Now, every graph $G$ (finite) has a max degree that is constant, and every graph $H$ is a partial $k$-tree for some natural number $k$.

And thus, the Subgraph Isomorphism problem for any pair of graphs $G$,$H$ can be solved in Polynomial time.

Then, why is the Subgraph Isomorphism problem classified as an NP-Hard problem?

Comment: The $k$ for $H$ to be a partial $k$ tree is not fixed and depends on the number of vertices in $H$. However, for something to be polynomial time, we need the exponent to be independent of the instant size. That is, independent of $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the theorem in question but I am pretty sure that $c$ should somehow figure into the runtime. But at any rate, this argument is incorrect:

> Now, every graph $G$ (finite) has a max degree that is constant, and every graph $H$ is a partial $k$-tree for some natural number $k$.

This is bit like saying that every graph has a number of vertices $n$ that is constant, so an $O(2^n)$ algorithm is polynomial (indeed, constant!).

In general, when we say that an algorithm runs in polynomial time, we have to specify what are the possible inputs, i.e. *what* is it polynomial in. In the case of graph theory, the input is the description of an arbitrary graph or graphs. Since the size of such a description is polynomial in the number of vertices, we can consider such an algorithm polynomial if its runtime is bounded by a polynomial of the number of vertices of the input graphs.

Now in our case $H$ might be a $(|V(H)|-1)$-tree (if it is complete), so the only bound we can give for $|V(G)|^{k+1} \cdot |V(H)|$ in terms of $|V(G)|$ and $|V(H)|$ is $|V(G)|^{|V(H)| + 1},$ which is clearly not polynomial in the two variables.

However, such an algorithm is valuable in showing, in a sense, *where* the complexity of the NP-hard problem lies. In this case it shows that if $G$ has small maximum degree and $H$ has small treewidth, then the problem is tractable.

Comment: I see what you are trying to say! Thank You for your insights. :)